# Bitcoin core syncing at 60% since December 13 and barely moving

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am using a macOS Sierra version 10.12.6. my wallet has been syncing since December 13, 2017 and is still at 60% and hardly advancing. Is this normal? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: You've been syncing since 1917?  Via telegraph???

Comment: I don't understand it, when did u sync it, what message did u get (e.g. connecting to peer)

Comment: @abelenky bitcoIN started around 2009 so that can't be possible

Comment: Duh! 2017! It just started syncing, showing progress rate and time left. I have a fairly new computer that has little stored on it .

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the blockchain many times (don't ask why).  Maybe a week or so, just depends, I didn't keep track of the time frame at that point.  If your network is slow, or your computer is slow (when verifying blocks), or if you're going through a VPN that slows you down, all those things could impact your download.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be because your computer is slow validating the blockchain but not necessarily. This [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/69862/75001) may help you.

Comment: Hi @Willtech: When you find a question who is completely answered on another question, please flag it as a duplicate of that corresponding question.