# Version 0.10.0 2009-2015

Tags: bitcoin-core

I downloaded Bitcoin Core Version 0.10.0 back in 2000 something.  I bought $ 100back then.  I forgot about it and I found the program, downloaded and its been syncing for 1 week.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sync with bitcoin-qt very slow (0,01%)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/sync-with-bitcoin-qt-very-slow-0-01). Time taken to sync can easily exceed a week. It depends in part on your PC specification and also on your Internet connection speed.

Comment: You should run updated versions for security reasons.